# How to Add Instagram in WordPress - MY site is built with Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, instagram, elementor

I'm working on project with [Efway theme](https://themeforest.net/item/efway-food-store-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/27965754) from Themelexus (https://themeforest.net/item/efway-food-store-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/27965754). On theme demo, I can not find feature for Instagram. I would like to add Instagram to my website but I don't know how to to.

Answer (score 1):

You can download this plugin from WordPress, install it and connect to your Instagram account
[plugin page in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/)

it's easy to install and configure, you will get a short-code when finish.

open a new page using elementor and add the short-code to a new short-code widget from the elementor sidebar and click update.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is a paid theme, you can contact to Themelexus provider to get instant support. I found the guide in their documentation: https://wpdocs.gitbook.io/medilazar/faqs/faqs/frequently-asked-questions

Efway theme and Medilazar theme are built with Elementor Page Builder. They are developed by Themelexus author. You can follow the same steps to do.